# Exporting CSV file to VCF

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, iphone, csv

I got a CSV file on Excel/Open Office and would like to import them on my iPhone but is proving an almost impossible task.

Some people suggested to send the file to myself via e.mail but, when choosing the software to open it, there is no "contacts" application that I choose from.

I think it may be easier if I converted the file to a VCF (vCards) list and then sent that to myself via e.mail.. would this trigger the right import program on my iPhone?

Any help/suggestion?

Comment: have you tried this links : http://vcardhosting.com/docs/csv-to-vcard-conversion-excel, http://www.csvtovcard.com/

Comment: It requires registration and I am not so keen on this. Seems like a void website really and I do not trust it as I don't know if it actually works and who stores my contact data.

Comment: Go for another link.. http://www.csvtovcard.com/ It's a software to be installed in Windows system. It might be harmless as you mentioned..

Comment: I found the same line but unfortunately I am under Mac Os. Thank u anyway

Comment: if you have number in cell A1, you can use this formula in B1, then copy B column to notepad, remove quotation marks and save file with .vcf extension. you can edit this formula for more fields or copy to other rows for more records:
=CONCATENATE("BEGIN:VCARD",CHAR(10),"VERSION:3.0",CHAR(10),"N:;",A1,"",CHAR(10),"FN:",A1,"",CHAR(10),"TEL;CELL:",A1,"",CHAR(10),"END:VCARD",CHAR(10))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the easiest way I found was to:

1. export excel file as CSV
2. import CSV file in Mac OS contacts (it allows to separate the
   various fields and assign them to a  traditional vCard field)
3. create a group within contacts (optional step)
4. sync my iPhone with the group via iTunes

Answer (score 0):

to be frank when i switch from Samsung S5 to apple iPhone 5S than i was facing same problem as i am able to get excel file in which i am able to get all the contact detail and my backup was in google.... as mostly people get this option in another android option as well... and i think my life is almost finished. thus one of my friend told me that vCard is a contact file which is compatible with samsung, Apple iPhone and also in windows system as well. so i start working on this and i get two options...

1. first method
   (i) sync all your contacts from your android phone to google
   (ii) now take your backup all your contacts in your phone by choosing vCard option.
   (iii) now copy all contacts file in your system
   (iv) now sync all these vCard file in your iPhone with the help of Itunes tool

To be frank its very much confusing and even today i am not able to rectify how these can be done but some of my tech friends know that and done it easily but still its very much confusing with me. they done it twice or thrice time but after that even me also feel embrace and this is the reason i find out another way and done all easily with the help of a thir party tool... http://exceltovcard.onlinetechaid.com which is free to download and below are the complete steps 
2. second step
(i) take backup of all your contacts from you google account by opening your account -> seetings -> backup - > contacts and store in excel file in your desirable location

(ii) download the free tool from the above given link and you will able to find out complete working detail of this tool in following link http://www.exceltovcard.onlinetechaid.com/how-it-works.html

(iii) after that simply download your Itunes and sync all your contacts in your contacts folder of iPhone and get all your contacts in your phone.

the best thing of vCard formatted contacts is user can use them as per need in any of device as well. Thus at that point of time this tool is very much useful and i feel blessed that i got this ultimate tool and there is no point of joy when i want to create distribution list and there is no option in some of my device but still i am able to make it with the help of this tool.... :) this is my personal experience and i hope that you will learn from my experience and able to solve all your problem... till than.. enjoy your life and spread happiness all over world.... :)